# Black screen brand new raspberry 3

Tags: raspbian, gui

I install raspbian **today** on micro sd card 16 go with Win32DiskImager to put the installation image on the card.
It start perfectly, I just install oh my zsh, XRDP, vim, set static ip.
I attempt to connect to it with remote connection feature from windows everythings works great.

Then, I shutdown it, move location to put on Ethernet and boot it without screen.
I attempt again to connect to it with remote connection feature but it "didn't" work (connection was successful but no GUI ) so I go back as before with screen mouse keyboard and surprise, black screen, no error.
I see the loading with "OK" and then redirect to a black screen with the white typing cursor. I'm able to use tty0 and type command, I tried some thing like rm Xauthority.
I don't have a clue of what happend and It's quite frustrating to be honest.
Any idea !? Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried reformatting your sd card?

Comment: No, because I'm trying to understand what really happen. I'm sure reformatting will solves this issue but if it comes again I don't want to reformat again and again :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo raspi-config
Expand Filesystem
Boot option > Desktop Autologin

I don't know why but problems solved

Comment: It solved your problem because the Pi natively boots into the command line and from their the command `startx` will load up the graphical user interface. When you setup auto login all it does is enter the command `startx` automatically on every boot

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue multiple times on my RasPi. Upon checking I found that OS allotted hdd usage was 100 % (in my case the 4 GB was completely full) so GUI was unable to work due to that. I had 8 GB card so to rectify this what I did was:

```
$sudo raspi-config
```

Select *expand filesystem* then it will ask for reboot